# Editing the memory and duplicating actions of a PC game?

Tags: debugging, memory, assembly, code-injection

There is a single player PC game with an in-game console which allows users to execute commands and set variables. My goal is to be able to, with an external program, execute commands as if they were entered through the console and to change the value of the variables.

I have experience programming, but have never done any game development and I also don't have very much knowledge on the inner-workings of programs.

As a start, I entered the command "set myvar myval" in the console and then did a search for "myval" in the program's memory (using HxD). I found multiple instances of the complete command "set myvar myval" and only one instance of just the value of the variable alone. Changing the value at this location changed the value in game, so I know it was the correct location of the variable's value. In a program, however, how would I know where to look for this variable's value? Are there only certain locations in the game's memory which would house the value, and within that space, would the values of the variables always be stored in the same range of memory? How would I increase the length of the value without crashing the program?

Are there any resources available online where I can learn about what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not so easy. There are no "certain locations" and you certainly can't rely on the location being always the same (which it most likely wont). And if the games has configurable variables, it likely will allocate memory on the fly for it. So the only chance I can see is, that you disassemble the code and look where the function is that creates such a variable. then you can call it with the appropriate parameters.

Answer (score 0):

In the golden age of WoW game, there was one tool that was doing thing you want by seaching program memory for certain values. So if you wanted very expensive item, you just had to search for that item´s ID, and then you replaced every occurence of your current item´s ID with ID of that expensive item. It was perfect, but it worked only until you tryied to log-out and log-in again. ID of your new item wasn't saved on server, so old item stayed on it`s place in you inventory.

Back on topic. You were able to find instances of `set myvar myval` string, but these instances aren't actually code of operation and of course the value of the `myvar`. Game commands are usually parsed and interepreted. If they were compiled, everything would be easier (as you would only need to find location of compiled code, and then put there your own code), but currently, you must find find the location of your variables by many tests.

The only two ways of finding the memory locations used by game are to disassembly, or to perform tests and statistically find the location - but in the world of dynamic memory allocation, this is almost impossible.

Changing 'length of the value' will usually surely cause problems in program, as the value`s exceed in memory can affect values of another ´variables´ important for program run.